# Read Csv file encoding error

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, csv, character-encoding

I am using the following method for reading Csv file content:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads data from a CSV file to a datatable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath">Path to the CSV file</param>
    /// <returns>Datatable filled with data read from the CSV file</returns>
    public DataTable ReadCsv(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            log.Error("Invalid CSV file name.");
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            string folder = FileMngr.Instance.ExtractFileDir(filePath);
            string fileName = FileMngr.Instance.ExtractFileName(filePath);
            string connectionString = 
            string.Concat(@"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=",
            folder, ";");

            using (OdbcConnection conn = 
                   new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string selectCommand = string.Concat("select * from [", fileName, "]");
                using (OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(selectCommand, conn))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error loading CSV content", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This method works if I have a *UTF-8* encoded Csv file with a *schema.ini* that looks something like this:

```
[Example.csv]
Format=Delimited(,)
ColNameHeader=True
MaxScanRows=2
CharacterSet=ANSI
```

If I have German characters in a Csv file with *Unicode* encoding, the method cannot read the data correctly.

What modifications can I make to the above method to read *Unicode* Csv files? If there is no way to do it this way, what Csv-reading code can you suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `CharacterSet=UNICODE` in your schema.ini file. Although this is not [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353.aspx) it works according to this [thread on Microsoft Forums](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/0ab1db1a-bfc4-48b6-b31e-33242abf18b2).

Comment: This could be what I was looking for! I am trying it now

Comment: This thing worked! This is some very useful piece of information right here! Thank you!

Comment: I used this in my connection string as opposed to the schema.ini file, but it worked just the same.

Comment: @Aaron Smith, can u send me example of your connection string how do u use it without schema.ini please?

Comment: @msony Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\;Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;CharacterSet=UNICODE;FMT=Delimited"

Answer (score 4):

Well, a very good and well-used streaming CSV reader [is on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx); that is the first thing I'd try... but it sounds like your encoding may be borked, which might not make it simple... of course, it could just be odbc that is breaking, in which case the above might work fine.

For simple CSV you could try parsing it yourself (`string.Split` etc), but there are enough edge-cases that a pre-rolled parser is worth using.